# React-Router params are not accessible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to receive the 'id' that is in the URI. But I am unable to collect it.

Route:

```
 <Route path="/reports/:id" >
       {!isLoggedIn ?
          <Redirect to="/login" /> : <UserReport userData={userData} />
       }
 </Route>
```

Link:

```
<Link to={'/reports/'+employee.id}>
    <span className="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style={{cursor:'pointer'}}>
          Report <FontAwesomeIcon icon="history" />
    </span>
</Link>
```

Component:

```
const UserReport = (props)=>{

    return (
        <div>
            {props.match.params.id}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Error:

**`It says props.match is undefined`**

But when I try the component attribute in Route, it works

```
 <Route path="/reports/:id" component={UserReport} >
```

**Is it possible to do this the way I am trying? Please help..This is my first React project.**

Comment: Check this, maybe this component can solve your problem https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

Comment: @Chaka15 thank you for the suggestion, but Mohiuddin's answer saved my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use useParams method from react-router-dom

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
const UserReport = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    return (
        <div>
            {id}
        </div>
    );
}
```